# How to make a function inside a class return a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14, std

I have a class and I want one of the class functions to take in a vector and return a different vector. I tried something like this but I get errors at the function declaration and definition saying that they don't match.

error messages:

```
example.cpp:11:18: error: prototype for ‘std::vector<int> myClass::myFunction(std::vector<double>&)’ does not match any in class ‘myClass’
 std::vector<int> myClass::myFunction(std::vector<dataType> & myVector){
                  ^
example.cpp:8:22: error: candidate is: std::vector<int> myClass::myFunction(const std::vector<double>&)
     std::vector<int> myFunction(const std::vector<dataType> & );
```

actual code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

typedef double dataType;

class myClass{
public:
    std::vector<int> myFunction(const std::vector<dataType> & );
};

std::vector<int> myClass::myFunction(std::vector<dataType> & myVector){
  std::vector<int> results;
  results.resize(myVector.size());
  for(int i=0; i<results.size(); ++i){
    results[i] = 0;
  }

  return results;
}

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the error messages.

Comment: If you get errors you should *always* include them *verbatim* in your question. We are not mind readers. We cannot guess your error messages.

Comment: You're missing a `const`.

Comment: @RickAstley where?

Comment: Your error message does not match the code. At all.

Comment: You implemented: `const std::vector<int>&  SetParallel::checkElements(std::vector<double>&)` You declared: `const std::vector<int>& SetParallel::checkElements(const std::vector<double>&)` Everything MUST match.

Comment: where do I need a const, at the beginning of both the function definition and declaration, or right after std::vector <int>?

Comment: @idknuttin please post your actual code

Comment: After I added `#include <vector>` to the example, and compiled it... no errors.

Comment: here is the code and error verbatim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the error messages, the function is

```
SetParallel::checkElements(std::vector<double>&)
```

the prototype is

```
SetParallel::checkElements(const std::vector<double>&)
```

(omitted initial `const std::vector<int>&` in both cases)

Can you see the difference?